# Memory allocation for struct using malloc where one of the data entries a pointer

Tags: c, pointers, struct, malloc

I understand the difference between memory allocation using malloc for an array of struct and for an array of pointers to struct. But I want to assign memory using malloc for an array of struct, in the case that the struct itself contains a pointer to another struct. Here is the code for what I am trying to do:

```
#include<stdio.h>
#include<stdlib.h>

typedef struct linkedlist {
    int pCol;
    struct linkedlist *next;
} plist;

typedef struct particle {
    int color;
    double rad;
    double rx;
    double ry;
    double vx;
    double vy;
    struct linkedlist *event;
} state;

int main()
{
    int N = 5, w = 4;

    plist *ls = (plist*)malloc((N+w)*sizeof(plist));
    printf("N=%d, w=%d, sizeof state=%d, total=%d, sizeof discs=%d\n\n",
    N,w,sizeof(plist), (N+w)*sizeof(plist), sizeof(ls));

    state *discs = (state*)malloc((N+w)*sizeof(state));
    printf("N=%d, w=%d, sizeof state=%d, total=%d, sizeof discs=%d\n",
    N,w,sizeof(state), (N+w)*sizeof(state), sizeof(discs));
    return 0;
}
```

When I run this, I get the following output:

```
N=5, w=4, sizeof plist=8, total=72, sizof ls=4

N=5, w=4, sizeof state=56, total=504, sizof discs=4
```

So, I want to know why does the ls or the discs get assigned only 4 bytes and how can I get *total* memory required assigned for these arrays of structs?

Comment: The total memory required for a pointer *is* 4 bytes (or 8, or 2, depending on platform). Think about that for a minute... it's *pointing* at something, not *containing* something. ;-)

Comment: `ls` and `discs` are of pointer type, which has size of 4bytes on 32-bit systems.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You are printing size of pointer(ls) and not size of datatype/structrure pointed by the pointer (*ls).

Do `sizeof(*ls)` and `sizeof(*discs)` in your printf statements if you intend to find size of `plist` and `state` because that is where `ls` and `discs` point to.

If you are thinking of printing the total size allocated to `ls` or `discs` by malloc. That is not possible. Its not going to print `((N+w)*sizeof(plist))`.
So even doing `sizeof(*ls)` is not going to tell you how many `plist` structures you allocated

Comment: I did do sizeof(*ls) and sizeof(*discs) in my printf codes but now the output becomes: N=5, w=4, sizeof state=8, total=72, sizeof ls=8 which means still size of *ls is not 72. Why?

Comment: You can't find the size of memory allocated to a pointer. You have to keep track of it yourself. If you do `sizeof(ptr)` it will give you size of ptr on that architecture. if you do `sizeof(*ptr)` it will give you the size of datatype/structure that ptr points too.

Answer (score 1):

in your code, `ls` is of type `plist *`,.i.e., a pointer.

`sizeof()` is an operator which returns the *size* of the data type, not the amount of memory allocated.

Same goes for `discs`.

Comment: Thanks for the explanation. But then, I have one more question. For sizeof(ls), the ans 4 bytes is right, but then how do I get to know the total memory allocated to the array of struct?

Comment: @Neha You cannot, at least not using `sizeof()`.

Comment: Well, and the reason behind downvote? If anyone explain, I'll be thankful.